# Upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.0 causes "The version of microsoft.net.sdk used by this project is insufficient" error

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.1 project that I'm trying to upgrade to version 2.0.  My project targets .NET Framework 4.62; not .NET Standard.

I have changed the nuget references in the .csproj file to their ASP.NET Core 2.0 equivalents.

I have Visual Studio 2017 update 3 installer.  I have *NOT* installed the .NET Core 2 SDK.

When I build the project on my local machine, everything works as expected.  I can run it and have no issues.

However, when I try to build the project on the build servers (which also have Visual Studio 2017 update 3), I get the following error:

> The version of microsoft.net.sdk used by this project is insufficient to support references targeting .NET Standard 1.5 or higher. Please install version 2.0 or higher or the .NET Core SDK.

I have tried adding:

```
<DependsOnNETStandard>false</DependsOnNETStandard>
```

To my .csproj file, however that caused compilation errors in my ASP.NET Core code.

Is it possible to get this to compile without having to install the SDK on all of our build servers (a painful IT process)?

Comment: Do you have a `TargetFramework` in the csproj file?

Comment: Yes, we have <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework> in the csproj file.

Comment: Have you added the Nuget NetStandard2.0 package to your net462 project?